# Very basic probability question of ball ? help

Tags: probability

Please help me out with very simple probability question ?

A bag contains 2 red, 3 green balls. One balls are drawn at random. What is the probability that  the ball drawn is red?

if the solution is 
P = 2c1/5c1 = 2/5

then my question is why there are two ways of selecting the red balls because they are identical so either you select the first or second one both are same cases ..

Here if we see sample space we get
s = {R},{G}
so how can there be 5 sample cases because the balls are identical.
Everywhere in questions over the internet it is not mentioned that it is identical or not
for example :
http://www.indiabix.com/aptitude/probability/
see 2nd question

Answer (score 2):

They are *not* identical. They are distinct and different. Let me take it to the extreme.

You have a bag with million black balls and one white ball. You draw a ball. What is the probability that it is white? is it 1/2?

You are confusing identical with looking the same. Let me give you another example. Suppose I have to give you cups of water. Do I give you two cups or just one because the two are identical?

Comment: So if in the question itself it is given that they are identical then bag with million black balls and one white ball would have the probability of drawing the white ball will be 1/2.....this don't make sense either..........please explain with approaching sample space

Comment: I also think that they are not distinct

Comment: Each ball is distinct. So you have to treat the million balls as being different.  You can't say, they are identical so why should I worry about how many there are. Which is why, when you have two red balls and 3 black balls, think of it as  "you have 5 balls of which two are red". Then you can see why the probability is 2/5. Another way is think them as $R_1$, $R_2$, $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$.

Comment: Note you have to number them even if the balls do not have a number written on them. Let me give you another analogy. You have two identical bars of gold each weighing 20 grams. How many do you have? The fact that they are identical does not mean you have only 20 grams. You have to count them as being distinct.

Comment: i totally understood your two points ....but what if the questions says they are not distinct i.e identical...then what will be sample space

Comment: Identical means that there is no way to differentiate between them when you put them through any (in this case probabilistic) tests. Take the example of two gold bars. Call them A and B. If I hold them in my hands, and keep one behind my back and show you one, *identical* means you can't tell if I am showing you A or B. I still have two bars and if you take one away from me, I will be very sad! So if it says the bag has two gold bars and 3 silver bars, all it says is that if I pull a bar and it is gold. I can't tell which bar it is. But there are still two bars.